# Python initialiser

Tags: python, initialization

I have this initialiser for a line class in Python and it takes two points as a parameter. The problem is my initialiser is only copying the references. So self.point0 and point 0 are pointing to the same object. I am not really sure how to change that so that I am not just copying the reference.
Line class:

```
def __init__(self, point0, point1): 
    self.point0 = point0
    self.point1 = point1
```

Point class:

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
```

Comment: Any particular reason for that?...as why you want that instead of pointing to the same object?

Comment: Yes, why do you want them distinct and why is `copy.copy` not satisfactory?

Comment: As defined, both `Line` and `Point` could easily be redefined as `namedtuple`s.  They'd be immutable, and perhaps would enforce the exclusivity you would prefer.  `copy.copy` would still work, as would creating new instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#module-copy) module:

```
import copy

def __init__(self, point0, point1):

        self.point0 = copy.copy(point0)
        self.point1 = copy.copy(point1)
```

This is required if your point objects are mutable, such as a lists or dictionaries. If you are using immutable types, such as a `tuple`, then it would not be required to make a copy.

If your points are represented as lists, you can also make a copy of the list using this syntax:

```
self.point0 = point0[:]
self.point1 = point1[:]
```

I could advise you with more certainty if you provided the definition of your point class.

---

**Update** after OP has posted `Point` class definition:

If `copy.copy()` is undesirable (why?) you can manually copy the attributes to the new `Point` instances:

```
class Line(object):
    def __init__(self, point0, point1):
        self.point0 = Point(point0.x, point0.y)
        self.point1 = Point(point1.x, point1.y)
```

Comment: @cleacrij  Please post the definition of your `Point` class in you question.

Comment: One way is to use tuples, or even `collections.namedtuple` for your Points... depends on what else your class is doing..

Comment: @cleacrij: If you want to continue with your `Point` class then you need to use `copy.copy()`, or create `Point` instances in `Line.__init__()` as shown in the update to my answer.